# html multiple class in one label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Firstname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Anna</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Debbie</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>John</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

it's a snippet from a bootstrap example.
noticed that it has multiple class in one label, so what's the relationship between these two class? it seems that **table-striped** is a subclass of **table**?

And how will the css change the style of this element? Will the style of **table-striped** override the style of **table**?

further more, how should I select this element by class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are still learning stuff here, If I am going to suggest it is far more better for learning sake to stay away from frameworks first until you learn how the basic stuff works, jumping ahead will just cause complications. Though anyway:

The classes you have mentioned does not have a relationship at all, actually all CSS classes do not have relationship at all. They stand out on their own for example:

```
.table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  // other common properties you find in a table
}
```

and there the other goes:

```
.table-striped {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  // other properties you can find on a striped table
}
```

as you invoke `table-striped` in a table that contains `table` class `table-striped` will just override the common properties of `table` which is `border` and apply it to the element.

How does it override? It is something I call precedence in CSS, whichever style comes last is always applied though later on you will encounter CSS overrides do not apply at all `IF` selectors do not match.

And the last thing: it does not matter how are you going to select the class as:

```
.table {
   // stuff
}

.table-striped {
   // stuff
}

// if selector contains both classes
.table.table-striped {
   // stuff
}

// if a table element contains .table class
table.table {
   // stuff
}

// and so on...
```

do not matter at all. Hope that helps you understand.

Comment: Great answer! In my experience though, `.table-striped` normally means there are different background colors for even and odd rows though.

Comment: It is just the `other` properties `.table-striped` can offer. As my example only applies on top level elements, later on there will be `.table striped tr td:nth-child(even) { // stuff }` which you cannot find in `.table` class

Comment: If you find it helpful and answers your problem do not forget to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will use the values from both classes and apply them to that element.

You can select the element based on each of them or both of them

```css
.cls-a {
  background: red;
}
.cls-b {
  color: blue;
}
.cls-a.cls-b {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls-a cls-b">Test</div>
```

Comment: what if there are conflict of the same attr in css for cls-a and cls-b? which one will be overrided? and does the order matter? I mean class="cls-a cls-b"     and class="cls-b cls-a"

Comment: This is related to specificity in css, you can check this for example: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

Multiple classes have does not mean that they have any relation to each other. As far as I know, `<table class="table table-striped">` is exactly the same as `<table class="table-striped table ">`.

You would select this table using its classes with any of the following combinations:

- `.table`
- `.table-stripped`
- `.table.table-stripped` or `.table-stripped.table`

How the CSS would be affected depends on the styles. By the names, I would assume that `.table` would style it as all bootstrap tables. `.table-stripped` would add different background colors for odd and even rows. [Example](http://www.browniesblog.com/A55CBC/blog.nsf/dx/stripedtable_chrome_small.png/$file/stripedtable_chrome_small.png)

Comment: Ordering of css classes only start to matter when using attribute selectors

Answer (score 0):

Those are just bootstrap css styling, you can have as much classes as you want on one element. You can add one more class after table-striped, create your own .css file and edit it as you want. Or you can add id to the table and style it like that.